# Javascript: Parsing a number with multiplication by 1.0

Tags: javascript

Is it safe to parse a number from a string like this?

```
rate *= 1.0;
sTraf.setDelay((rate+1)*1000);
```

`rate` is a string which contains only 1 number.

Comment: what's wrong do you think so?

Comment: Why don't you just use "parseFloat" ?

Comment: You can use the unuary `+rate` to get a number from a string

Comment: This is a part of an embedded html page. We have 100 uses of *1.0. We wanted to save memory space by not using parseFloat/parseInt (file size). @Hacketo: will check this, thx.

Comment: *"from a string like this"* I don't see a string.

Comment: @Felix Kling: True there... rate is a string before the *1.0

Comment: But whether this is "safe" to do depends on the possible values of the string. Also there is no "parsing" happening in your example at least.

Comment: @Felix Kling: It is a "hidden" parsing. if rate is "5" (string), after the "parsing" it is 5 (number).

Comment: That's type conversion. I guess one could say that converting a string to a different data type always involves some from of parsing, but given that there are functions which really performs some parsing (`parseInt`, `parseFloat`), and which also has a different outcome that just type conversion, I would avoid conflating those two, at least in JavaScript.

Comment: @Felix Kling: I come from the embedded world so getting a number from a string is always parsing :)  Thanks for your clarifications!

Comment: Fair enough :) The most explicit way to convert something to a number would be to call the `Number` function: `Number(rate)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend it. The snippet is unclear: the real intention is hidden in the implicit side-effect of multiplication (javascript tries to cast non-numerical variables to their numerical "equivalent") instead of being clear and visible from the code.

If you use `parseFloat`, it's clear to everyone reading your code what you're trying to do: you have a string that should be parsable as a float, and you want to cast it. Also, being a function written purposely for that job, it has all the necessary "failsafes" for edge cases.

If you really want / have to use `* 1.0` for some strange reason, at the very least you should put the purpose of your code (which is to cast a string to a float, not to multiply by 1) in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Generally no, if `rate` can't be parsed, it will be set to `NaN` which may causes errors depending on what you do with it.

If you can be sure that `rate` is a number you can use `rate = +rate` to get a number.

Comment: In this example, rate is an int between 1 to 10.